# nginx + PHP-FPM farm?

Tags: nginx, cluster, php-fpm

I have a setup with two small servers running nginx serving as proxy and a number of Apache+mod_php beefy servers. I am thinking on going over to PHP-FPM. Can I configure nginx to use a number of FastCGI servers? Or PHP-FPM itself to use workers on different machines? Or do I need to run nginx on the workers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no you can run 1 nginx machine and many php-fpm machines.

```
upstream php {
  server 10.0.0.1:9000;
  server 10.0.0.2:9000;
  server 10.0.0.3:9000;
}
```

Then in your locaction

```
fastcgi_pass php;
```

Comment: Thanks! That was totally not clear from the documentation.

Comment: What about keep alive connections? What should the number of keep alive be?

Answer (score 1):

A complement to Mike's answer.

Check this [vulnerability](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/) that can arise when you have nginx and PHP-FPM in different servers. The bottom line is: don't allow users to upload content to your public directory.

Comment: this got fixed in php >=5.3.9 [issue](https://disq.us/url?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbugs.php.net%2Fbug.php%3Fid%3D55181%3AaQuKoujCOhGb9OxfGdB83t6aAgc&cuid=1200067)